Can't seem to get the date parameter to work
The following query works when I don’t add the last AND statement with the dates. However, when I add it, no results are found. I know this isn’t true because I populate data into the engine and know it’s there. I just can’t query it this way. Do you have any thoughts as to why?
SELECT *
FROM
     othertablename HOS
     INNER JOIN tablename OBS ON HOS.unique_id = OBS.unique_id
WHERE
     (HOS.result LIKE 'Pos%' OR HOS.result LIKE 'Detect%')
     AND hos.loinc IN ('100156-9',...'99825-2')
     AND HOS.specimen_col_dt > '01-MAY-24'

I was expecting to get rows back with data populated, but I am getting nothing when I add this AND HOS.specimen_col_dt > '01-MAY-24'. And if I take that part away, I get data.

Start your question by tagging it properly.  Date functions vary for different dbms.  So which dbms are you using???

And also what date format are correct in string format vary by RDBMS, and typically also depend on locale settings.
